# Does Harbor registry garbage collector remove all untagged images?

Tags: docker, containers, registry, harbor

I deleted some repositories from the Harbor registry UI; however, the disk space is not being freed up. I want to completely remove the repositories that I deleted from the UI, but I also want to retain my untagged images in other repositories. Does Harbor's garbage collection (GC) process completely delete all untagged (dangling) images, or does it only remove the ones associated with the deleted repositories?

Answer (score 1):

if you select the option `Allow garbage collection on untagged artifacts` then  untagged artifacts will be deleted too.